# SQL Select Rows where a value of a multiple value field occurs only once

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following problem:

I have a table with different columns describing objects. One of this column let's assume can contain the values 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10. Within this table objects can contain all of these values or some just contain for example value 1,3,5 (so 0 to n values)

Now I want to find all the objects containing only the value 1 and 2, but I do not want them in my result set if they contain 1,2,3 or other combinations but (1,2).

How do I write this SQL statement?

Sample data (Result set to be expected --> Mark and Michael):

```
+---------+--------------------+---------------------------+--+
|   OBJ   | OBJ_CHARACTERISTIC | CHARACTERISTIC_DATE_ADDED |  |
+---------+--------------------+---------------------------+--+
| Mark    |                  1 |                15.01.2018 |  |
| Mark    |                  2 |                15.02.2018 |  |
| Jimmy   |                  1 |                31.01.2018 |  |
| Jimmy   |                  2 |                11.02.2018 |  |
| Jimmy   |                  4 |                15.03.2018 |  |
| Jimmy   |                  5 |                15.04.2018 |  |
| Jimmy   |                  6 |                15.04.2018 |  |
| Harry   |                  1 |                08.01.2018 |  |
| Harry   |                  2 |                11.01.2018 |  |
| Harry   |                  3 |                15.02.2018 |  |
| Michael |                  1 |                15.06.2018 |  |
| Michael |                  2 |                15.07.2018 |  |
| Dwayne  |                  4 |                15.01.2018 |  |
| Dwayne  |                  5 |                15.01.2018 |  |
| Dwayne  |                  6 |                15.01.2018 |  |
+---------+--------------------+---------------------------+--+
```

Comment: using an oracle database

Comment: It isn't clear if this is a string value containing comma-separated values, or multiple rows with one value in each, with a common ID - hopefully the latter. Please give useful data examples [in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51185656/edit), as [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) ([*not* images](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)).

Comment: I am trying, somewhat failing uploading my sample data as a table, tried now as an image. but trying now as formatted text

Comment: With that sample data, what is the expected result?

Comment: Mark, and Michael (so the objects having only the object characteristics with value 1 and 2

Comment: Column "OBJ_CHARACTERISTIC" - is number type? And it only can be integer values? Or any other value, even varchar2 type?

Comment: @Ychdziu yes only number type (integer)

Answer (score 2):

You could use analytic counts to see how many characteristics each object has, and how many of the ones you are looking for; and then compare those counts:

```
select obj, obj_characteristic, characteristic_date_added
from (
  select obj, obj_characteristic, characteristic_date_added,
    count(distinct obj_characteristic) over (partition by obj) as c1,
    count(distinct case when obj_characteristic in (1,2) then obj_characteristic end)
      over (partition by obj) as c2
  from your_table
)
where c1 = c2;
```

With your sample data that gives:

```
OBJ     OBJ_CHARACTERISTIC CHARACTERI
------- ------------------ ----------
Mark                     1 2018-01-15
Mark                     2 2018-02-15
Michael                  1 2018-06-15
Michael                  2 2018-07-15
```

From the way the question is worded it sounds like you want the complete rows, as above; froma comment you may only want the names. If so you can just change the outer select to:

```
select distinct obj
from ...

OBJ    
-------
Mark
Michael
```

or use aggregates instead via a `having` clause:

```
select obj
from your_table
group by obj
having count(distinct obj_characteristic)
  = count(distinct case when obj_characteristic in (1,2) then obj_characteristic end);

OBJ    
-------
Mark
Michael
```

[db<>fiddle demo of all three](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=74c7de87cf55b2abbc9c2f038849d450).

---

In this case, as 1 and 2 are contiguous, you could also do this with min/max, as an aggregate to just get the names:

```
select obj
from your_table
group by obj
having min (obj_characteristic) = 1
and max(obj_characteristic) = 2;
```

or analytically to get the complete rows:

```
select obj, obj_characteristic, characteristic_date_added
from (
  select obj, obj_characteristic, characteristic_date_added,
    min(obj_characteristic) over (partition by obj) as min_char,
    max(obj_characteristic) over (partition by obj) as max_char
  from your_table
)
where min_char = 1
and max_char = 2;
```

but the earlier versions are more generic.

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex! I have to add though two things: 1) The table is extremely large. 2) I should have pointed out as well in the table that for example Mark might have 4 times the obj_characteristic 1 and not just once 1 and once 2

Comment: @dwin90 - that's why I included `distinct` in the counts. It doesn't matter how many 1s and 2s they have, only that they have at least one of each, and nothing else. Or do you mean you only want to list them if they have exactly one of each?

Comment: Ah ok, got it. No so, if they have (1,2) then they should occur in the result set. But if they have (1,1,1,1,1,2) they should occur as well. Or if they have (1,2,1,2,1,2) they should also occur. Problem now is just that the query is not very fast :) so it's still running..

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking for sql to return rows values '1,2' and nothing else use:

```
select * from table where column like '%1,2'
```

Post an example of the data, it may be more helpful to understand.

Comment: Thanks for answering, yet it is not really what I need. I posted a sample result set now. Hopefully it's clear now what my goal is

Answer (score 0):

@dwin90 You could try:

```
SELECT obj
FROM your_table
WHERE (OBJ_CHARACTERISTIC=1 OR OBJ_HARACTERISTIC=2 AND OBJ_CHARACTERISTIC !> 2
)GROUP BY OBJ
```